# Difference between 'busy-wait' infinite loop and condition validation infinite loop

Tags: c, multithreading, sdl

Given the following code example from SDL wiki:

```
SDL_bool condition = SDL_FALSE;
SDL_mutex *lock;
SDL_cond *cond;

lock = SDL_CreateMutex();
cond = SDL_CreateCond();
.
.
Thread A:
SDL_LockMutex(lock);
while (!condition) {
    SDL_CondWait(cond, lock);
}
SDL_UnlockMutex(lock);

Thread B:
SDL_LockMutex(lock);
...
condition = SDL_TRUE;
...
SDL_CondSignal(cond);
SDL_UnlockMutex(lock);
```

Why is it considered more efficient to use a conditional wait (SDL_CondWait) 
then just use an inifnite global variable loop , e.g.:

```
while (!condition);
```

it looks (to me) that they are both busy-waiting for the variable condition to become true, only difference is that the cond loop also checks if a different thread 'signaled' the cond variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because waiting on a condition variable is a non-busy wait. The CPU isn't actually doing any work. Instead, the thread is idle, waiting on a signal. The thread is not given any CPU resources until the condition is signaled.

When the condition is signaled, the thread becomes eligible again, and the scheduler can once again allocate CPU resources to it.

Contrast that to the busy wait loop, `while (!condition)`, which spins in a tight loop, continually checking the `condition` variable.

The reason for the loop is that the condition might be signaled, but then the lock might be taken by somebody else before this thread gets it. So rather than a tight loop checking for the condition to be true, you have a series of relatively long non-busy waits, each followed by a single test.

See [Condition Variables](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/MONITOR/CV.html) for more detail.